# Django template instructions leave space

Tags: python, django, templates

Instructions like `{% block %}` and `{% load %}` leave empty newline after themselves. How can one turn off this feature ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaceless works.  It doesn't remove space inside HTML tags within it (but that's a feature, so it doesn't remove all spaces in say a paragraph of text).  Do you have a new line before spaceless?  Can you give a failing example, tell us your django version (not that it should be relevant?)

E.g., I have code like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/dashboard.css" /> 
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/ie.css" /><![endif]-->{% spaceless %}
{% block extrahead %}

{% endblock %} 
{% endspaceless %}
<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" /> 
</head>
```

and when I look at the html-source is rendered like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/referring_md/media/css/dashboard.css" /> 
<!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/ie.css" /><![endif]--> 
<meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" /> 
</head>
```

Comment: haven't tried encapsulating a whole block inside spaces,just contents of the block. Seems it works :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a "spaceless" tag, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Answer (score 2):

> There is a "spaceless" tag, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/

or you just dont make a newline in/after a block/load tag.

Comment: you can off course put the at the end of a line above, but this can be a really long line and spaceless block does not work